# AWS S3 js SDK: Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to utilize AWS js SDK in my ASP.NET Core 3 web application to access s3 bucket on client and it doesn't work.

1. I've created a bucket and added following CORS configuration to it:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
   <CORSRule>
       <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
       <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
       <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
       <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
   </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>
   ```
2. I've created a new IAM user with AmazonS3FullAccess rights with an AccessKey and a Secret.
3. I've added a added a simple View to verify it with following Scripts section:

   ```
   <script src="/lib/aws/aws-sdk-2.592.0.js"></script>
   <script language="javascript">
       $(function() {

           AWS.config.update({
               region: 'eu-west-2',
               credentials: new AWS.Credentials('<key>', '<secret>')
           });

           var s3 = new AWS.S3({
               apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
               params: { Bucket: '<bucket>' }
           });

           s3.listObjectsV2(function(err, data) {
                   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
                   else {
                       data.Contents.forEach(function(element) {
                           var row = "<tr>" + 
                                   "<td>" + element.Key + "</td>" + 
                                   "<td>" + element.LastModified + "</td>" + 
                                   "<td>" + element.Etag + "</td>" + 
                                   "<td>" + element.Size + "</td>" + 
                                   "<td>" + element.StorageClass + "</td>" + 
                                   "</tr>"
                           $('#objects-list-table tbody').append(row);
                       });
                   }
               });
       });
   </script>
   ```

And I keep getting following errors in browser console, like there is no CORS configured for bucket:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://<bucket>.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2' from origin 'https://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/?max-keys=0' from origin 'https://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

What is wrong with my configuration? How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spoofed all HTTP requests with HTTP Toolkit and found, that the region is incorrect. 
In case if somebody have the same issue and CORS config seems correct - check the region.

In my case, Frankfurt server is not eu-west-2, but **eu-central-1**

Comment: Does anybody understood this answer?

Comment: You need more clarification?